# Java Akka actor's HTTP POST request not hitting the post path

Tags: java, post, akka, akka-http

I am creating a post request using akka version 2.6.17 and akka http 10.2.7. My system is bound to port 8080 and can receive post requests from Postman just fine. However, when sending a post request from within akka itself (an actor sending a post request), the POST path is never hit.
Here is the post request

```
public void postStockCheck(){
        String data = "{\"id\": \"yes\"}";
        HttpRequest.POST("http://localhost:8080/hello")
        .withEntity(HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8, data));
    }
```

Here is the path:

```
return route(
        path("hello", () ->
            post(() ->
                entity(Unmarshaller.entityToString(), (string) -> {
                  System.out.println("request body: " + string);
                  return complete("Success");
                })
              )));
      }
```

As mentioned, the path will work from postman. If I'm missing something, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `postStockCheck` you have created a `HttpRequest`, but haven't fired it. To fire the request you could use `singleRequest` method from `Http`.

```
public void postStockCheck(ActorSystem system) {
    String data = "{\"id\": \"yes\"}";

    Http.get(system)
            .singleRequest(HttpRequest.POST("http://localhost:8080/hello")
            .withEntity(HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8, data)));
}
```

To get a better picture of firing the request and collecting responses, go through the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html).